# Создание корректных запросов для yandex.tank\phantom

Tags: яндекс-танк

Т.к. я только начинаю знакомиться с танком, возник еще один вопрос - как правильно задать ему запрос. Имеется локальный web-сервер, на нем крутиться небольшой сайт. К нему напрямую подключен сервер с танком. Нагрузка генерируется фантомом. Но апач постоянно выдает в логах `ssl` ошибку `Invalid URI in request`. Можете посоветовать, чем можно "вытащить" корректные запросы к сайту? `wget`? может быть, `curl`?

UPD

пример вывода `answ.log`:

```
208 488 35886 852 0
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Thu, 28 Jan 2016 13:39:50 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
Content-Length: 289
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
ERROR 404: Not Found.
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request^M
Date: Tue, 02 Feb 2016 10:56:39 GMT^M
Server: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)^M
Content-Length: 307^M
Connection: close^M
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1^M
^M
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />
</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) Server at 192.168.238.211 Port 443</address>
</body></html>

366 488 35985 688 0
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 28 Jan 2016 13:39:50 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
Last-Modified: Sat, 26 Jun 2010 09:38:02 GMT
ETag: "369-489eba4cc1280"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 873
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/css
                                         0K                                                       100% 44,7M=0s
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request^M
Date: Tue, 02 Feb 2016 10:56:39 GMT^M
Server: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)^M
Content-Length: 307^M
Connection: close^M
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1^M
^M
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />
</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) Server at 192.168.238.211 Port 443</address>
</body></html>
```

`load.ini`:

```
[phantom]
threads=60
phantom_path=/usr/bin/phantom
phantom_modules_path=/usr/lib/phantom/
instances=5000
address=192.168.238.211 ;Target's address
port=443 ;target's port
rps_schedule=const(1000,30s) ;load scheme
writelog=all
gatling_ip=192.168.238.210 ;generator's network interface
ammofile=https://192.168.238.211/ammo/ammo.txt
ssl=1
```

Comment: Включите опцию ```writelog=all``` в секции ```phantom```. Танк запишет answ.log -- там будут и запросы и ответы от сервера. Покажите, что получилось -- разберемся.
И покажите конфиг еще.

Comment: Добавил информацию в основной вопрос

Comment: Либо в ammo.txt находится что-то странное, либо на этапе выкачивания https://192.168.238.211/ammo/ammo.txt возникли проблемы. Покажите кусочек ammo.txt и еще попробуйте на машине с танком вручную вытянуть https://192.168.238.211/ammo/ammo.txt

Comment: `wget` выкачивает `ammo.txt` по ссылке `https://<адрес>/<путь_к_файлу>` только с дополнительной опцией `--no-check-certificate`

Comment: пример запроса в `ammo.txt`: `423
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  Date: Thu, 28 Jan 2016 13:39:50 GMT
  Server: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
  Last-Modified: Sun, 03 Oct 2010 06:50:52 GMT
  ETag: "3f0-491b0d9408b00"
  Accept-Ranges: bytes
  Content-Length: 1008
  Connection: close
  Content-Type: text/css
  Length: 1008 [text/css]
  Saving to: ‘192.168.238.211/css/grid.css’

                       0K                                                       100% 50,2M=0s`

Comment: Воо, теперь ясно - в ammo.txt у вас не запросы, а ответы =)      
"HTTP/1.1 200 OK" и далее - это ответ на некий запрос

Comment: вот как раз об этом и речь =) Хотелось бы понять, как корректно получить необходимые запросы? наткнулся на `wget`, но так и не смог с ним нормально разобраться (подсказали лишь то, что их как раз можно с помощью его получить). Но с данным направлением впервые имею дело...

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В комментах уже выяснили, что у вас неверный формат запросов, как нужно делать [описано в документации](http://yandextank.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#uri-style-uris-in-file).

На практике наиболее используемые `uri-style` и `request-style`. `Uri-style` – это просто список `uri` в отдельном файле, опционально после `uri` через пробел можно задать тег, тогда будут дополнительные агрегаты по тегам; заголовки задаются в любом месте в `[]` и применяются ко всем последующим запросам:

```
[Connection: close]
[Host: example.com]
/
/test?param=1
```

Если у вас только GET запросы - этого достаточно.

Чтобы слать запросы произвольного вида нужно использовать request-style, там содержимое запроса отправляется практически "как есть" исправляются только переводы строки в заголовках на `\r\n` при необходимости, формат [описан в документации](http://yandextank.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#request-style).

Собрать GET запросы можно по логам веб-сервера, с POST/PUT сложнее, если нужны они то, можно сделать генератор под конкретный сервис, узнав, что за данные в него нужно слать. Если нет хорошего описания, что за данные надо слать, можно посмотреть, что фактически отправляется - или через developer tools браузера или при помощи утилит для захвата трафика, например, `wireshark` (с https тут будут проблемы).

Comment: Спасибо! Вытащил необходимые GET/POST через developer tools (странно, что сам не подумал об этом раньше). Теперь все работает как нужно!